# Cybersecurity (Internet topology classification)

Tags: security, data-analysis

I am trying to draw some insights on a set of Autonomous System (AS) relationships given to me. Data looks like this -

```
as1   as2   relationship

 4     567      0       

14     6079     0

18     276      0

18    26468     0

24     293      0

24    6509      0

24    7575      0

24    10343    -1

24    11537     0

24    19401     0

24    27750     0

26    19401     0

31    567       0

32    71       -1
```

I believe that 0 and -1 indicate whether relationship is c->p or p->p, but I am not sure. Please help me identify what this data actually means and what insights could I possibly draw from a set of 250000 such points spread over 2 days and how?

Comment: I'd rather assume -1 indicates a disconnect. But don't ask us to know what your data means...

Answer (score 2):

The AS columns show Autonomous System Numbers (ASNs), which are globally unique 32-bit numbers assigned by the Regional Internet Registry (RIR) of the country of registration (e.g., American Registry for Internet Numbers (ARIN) for the United States) to each AS. For example, in the first line, 4 represents the University of Southern California (see http://as-rank.caida.org/asns/4 for reference) and 567 represents Los Nettos, as revealed at http://as-rank.caida.org/asns/567, which are actually AS neighbors.